# Ansible playbook для просмотра cron на удаленных серверах

Tags: linux, bash, ansible, yaml

Написал небольшой playbook для копирования задач крон в отдельный файл на серверах.

```
- name: crontab jobs list on all servers
  hosts: all
  become: yes

  vars:
    file: /var/log.txt

  tasks:
  - name:

    shell: "echo '########################################' >> {{ file }} && echo server_name: {{ ansible_hostname }} >> {{ file }} && echo server_ip: {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }} >> {{ file }} && crontab -l >> {{ file }}; crontab -l 2>> {{ file }}
```

Все работает, но криво - хотелось бы иметь отдельный файл на сервере ansible со всеми задачами cron.

Добавил в плейбук

```
 tasks:
  - name:

    shell: "echo '########################################' >> {{ file }} && echo server_name: {{ ansible_hostname }} >> {{ file }} && echo server_ip: {{ ansible_all_ipv4_addresses }} >> {{ file }} && crontab -l >> {{ file }}; crontab -l 2>> {{ file }}

    delegate_to: 127.0.0.1
```

Файл создался, но почему-то все значения - no crontab for root, хотя на одном сервере были задачи в cron.

```
root@lab:/home/user# cat /var/log.txt
########################################
server_name: lab
server_ip: [10.0.2.15, 172.16.22.221]
no crontab for root
########################################
server_name: 10
server_ip: [10.0.2.15, 172.16.22.224]
no crontab for root
########################################
server_name: lab2
server_ip: [172.16.22.223, 10.0.2.15]
no crontab for root
```

Помогите разобраться в чем причина.

Comment: Эммм... а почему ты используешь `shell`, а не `cron`?

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `crontab -l` показывает только задачи которые добавленны через `crontab -e`

Хранятся они в /var/spool/cron/crontabs/, там есть списки и для других пользователей. Дергай через

```
cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*
```

Системный /etc/crontab и /etc/cron.d/ там не отображаются. Тоже проще через cat

```
cat /etc/crontab
cat /etc/cron.d/*
```

Вместо звездочки напиши цикл чтоб имена файлов указать:

```
for i in /etc/cron.d/*
do
  echo Файл "$i"
  cat "$i"
done
```

Следует заглянуть ещё через ls

```
ls /etc/cron.daily/   /etc/cron.hourly/  /etc/cron.monthly/ /etc/cron.weekly/
```

Comment: `cat /var/spool/cron/crontabs/*` я так тоже пробовал, результат тот же. Проблема как мне кажется с delegate_to. Так как без него результаты от плейбука записываются на самих серверах нормально. 

```server_name: lab
server_ip: [10.0.2.15, 172.16.22.221]
0 5 * * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
0 5 3 * 1 tar -zcf /var/backups/home.tgz /home/
#Ansible: check dirs
0 5,2 * * * ls -alh > /dev/null```
Создавал через crontab -e